# Real Analysis Question 6

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying for an exam and I came across the following problem and got stuck.  I was hoping that someone might be able to help me out.

Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions from $X$ to $[0, \infty]$.  Suppose $f_n$ decreases pointwise to $f$, and $\int f_1 < \infty$.  Show that $\int f = \lim \int f_n.$

Comment: If really you are studying for an exam and the exam is soon, you might as well be reminded the need to learn the few main results of the subject. Without a doubt, MCT is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Your functions $f_n$ are dominated by the integrable function $f_1$, so you can apply the dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 1):

You can see [the monotone convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem.)

Comment: To the downvoter, consider the sequence $g_n = f_1-f_n$.